# How to make this top border with css?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how I can make this top border in css and how it is called because i have no idea.
[image]

I tried messing with ::before and ::after but it simply wont look good.

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: grey;
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.container:after {
  content: '';
  background: red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: is it rounded or a triangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `clip-path` and `polygon` to create triangle on top. Use `left` and `width` property wisely so you dont see the left and right part of the traingle.

See the Snippet below:

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: #FFCC00;
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.container:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 2.5%;
    top: -20px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 95%;
    height: 20px;
    background: #FFCC00;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 30%, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(50% 30%, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways to do it

[image: first way]

[image: second way]

and you can learn how to make triangle here
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_shapes.asp

Answer (score -1):

I was able to make it using clip path.
This is the tool that I've used: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/